# Tabla de multiplicar con javascript del 1 al 10

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer una tabla de multiplicr con javascript haciendo que un usuario ingrese el numero en una ventana emergente, pero la tabla de multiplicar debe tener un rango del 1 al 10 si el usuario ingresa un numero mayor que 10 y un numero menor que 1  debe aparecer el mensaje “El número que me has dado no está entre el 1 y el 10.  Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo.”, pero no soy capaz de hacerlo asi lo llevo.

```js
    window.onload = function(){
    numero = prompt("Introduce un número: ");
    document.write("<table border='1'><tr><td>Número</td><td>Resultado</td></tr>");
        for(i=0; i<=10; i++){
            document.write("<tr><td>"+numero+" x " + i +"</td><td>" + numero * i + "</td></tr>");
        }
    document.write("</table>");
}
```

Comment: Te hace falta el uso de condicionales (**`if`**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes poner una sentencia if antes del for, en la cual validaras que el numero que ingresan cumpla con la condición de ser mayor a 0 y menor o igual a 10

```
window.onload = function(){
  numero = prompt("Introduce un número: ");
  if (numero < 1 || numero > 10) {
      alert("El número que me has dado no está entre el 1 y el 10. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo.");
  return;
  }
  document.write("<table border='1'><tr><td>Número</td><td>Resultado</td></tr>");
    for(i=0; i<=10; i++){
        document.write("<tr><td>"+numero+" x " + i +"</td><td>" + numero * i + "</td> 
    </tr>");
    }
document.write("</table>");
}
```

Comment: Primero debes transformar de string a number

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso, a parte de verificar si es mayor que 10 y menor que 0, también verifico si hay número o si no es un número.

Si no cumple una de esas 4 condiciones, te retorna otra vez el `prompt` hasta que lo hagas.

Una vez obtenido el número, le aplicas un `parseInt` para hacerlo como valor numérico y así poder operar con el libremente.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
    //Metemos el resultado de la funcion en num
    let num = selectNum();
    //creamos la tabla
    document.write("<table border='1'><tr><td>Número</td><td>Resultado</td></tr>");
    //iniciamos un bucle for para hacer la tabla con 10 valores posibles
    for(let i = 1; i <= 10;i++){
        //obtenemos el resultado
        var res = num * i;
        //metemos en las celdas los resultados
        document.write("<tr><td>"+num+" x " + i +"</td><td>" + res + "</td></tr>");
    }
});

//Iniciamos la function
function selectNum(){
    //Pedimos por el prompt un numero
    var num = prompt('Escoge un número');
        //Iniciamos un bucle while
        while(!num || isNaN(num) || num < 0 || num > 10){ //mientras que no haya num (!num) o no sea un numero (isNaN(num), mayor que 10 o menor que 0
        if (num < 0) {
            alert('Escoge un numero mayor que 0');
        }
        else if( num > 10){
            alert('Escoge un numero menor que 10');
        }
        num = prompt('Escoge un número válido');   //vuelve a meter un valor, no podrá usar otro valor que no sea numerico
        }
    //Ya que el prompt nos devuelve un valor en texto, lo parseamos a numeral
    var num = parseInt(num);
    //retornamos el numero con valor numerico, y no como texto (se muestra en verde)
    return num
}
```